# Create an iterator and put it into a new struct without bothering the borrow-checker

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am trying to create a lexical analyzer which uses `itertools::PutBack` to make an iterator over the characters in a `String`. I intend to store the pushback iterator in a struct and delegate methods to it so that I can categorize the characters by an enum, which will then be passed to  a state machine at the core of the lexical analyzer (not yet written).

The borrow-checker is not happy with me. Method `ParserEventIterator::new` near the bottom of the listing causes the error. How do I define the lifetimes or borrowing so that I can get this to compile? Or what Rustic data structure design should I use in its stead?

Ultimately, I would like this to implement the appropriate traits to become a proper iterator. (Newbie to Rust. Prior to this, I have programmed in 28 languages, but this one has me stumped.)

Here is a code sample:

```
extern crate itertools;
use itertools::put_back;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::fmt::Formatter;
use std::fmt::Result;

pub enum ParserEvent {
    Letter(char),
    Digit(char),
    Other(char),
}

impl ParserEvent {
    fn new(c: char) -> ParserEvent {
        match c {
            'a'...'z' | 'A'...'Z' => ParserEvent::Letter(c),
            '0'...'9' => ParserEvent::Digit(c),
            _ => ParserEvent::Other(c),
        }
    }
}

impl Display for ParserEvent {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result {
        let mut _ctos = |c: char| write!(f, "{}", c.to_string());
        match self {
            ParserEvent::Letter(letter) => _ctos(*letter),
            ParserEvent::Digit(digit) => _ctos(*digit),
            ParserEvent::Other(o) => _ctos(*o),
        }
    }
}

//  ParserEventIterator
//  Elements ('e) must have lifetime longer than the iterator ('i).
pub struct ParserEventIterator<'i, 'e: 'i> {
    char_iter: &'i mut itertools::PutBack<std::str::Chars<'e>>,
}

impl<'i, 'e: 'i> ParserEventIterator<'i, 'e> {
    fn new(s: &'e std::string::String) -> ParserEventIterator<'i, 'e> {
        // THIS NEXT LINE IS THE LINE WITH THE PROBLEM!!!
        ParserEventIterator {
            char_iter: &mut put_back(s.chars()),
        }
    }

    fn put_back(&mut self, e: ParserEvent) -> () {
        if let Some(c) = e.to_string().chars().next() {
            self.char_iter.put_back(c);
        }
    }
}

impl<'i, 'e: 'i> Iterator for ParserEventIterator<'i, 'e> {
    type Item = ParserEvent;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<ParserEvent> {
        match self.char_iter.next() {
            Some(c) => Some(ParserEvent::new(c)),
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut _i = ParserEventIterator::new(&String::from("Hello World"));
}
```

[On the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b02afdef23533d8c2667c954202d0a1a)

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:43:9
   |
43 | /         ParserEventIterator {
44 | |             char_iter: &mut put_back(s.chars()),
   | |                             ------------------- temporary value created here
45 | |         }
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the compiler is almost telling you the solution by reflecting to the obvious problem: you can't have a borrow which doesn't live long enough, i.e. the borrow would point to a nonexistent location after the stack memory of the function has been destroyed.

This would happen because the borrow is referencing an object (in this case an `itertools::struct::PutBack` instance) that has been newly created within the function body.  This instance gets destroyed at the end of the function along with all the references to it.  So the compiler is preventing you to have a so called *dangling pointer*.

Thus, instead of borrowing you should **move** the `PutBack` instance into your `struct`:

```rust
// ...

pub struct ParserEventIterator<'e> {
    char_iter: itertools::PutBack<std::str::Chars<'e>>
}

impl<'e> ParserEventIterator<'e> {
    fn new(s: &'e std::string::String) -> ParserEventIterator<'e> {
        ParserEventIterator { char_iter: put_back(s.chars()) }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: What you suggest was in fact my starting point. It yields this error:       |                                          expected mutable reference, found struct `itertools::PutBack`
    |                                          help: consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut put_back(s.chars() }`

Comment: Then if I follow that advice, i get `returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`

Comment: I didn't notice your changes to the lifetimes. Testing it again.

Comment: Your proposal compiles! On to the next problem...

Comment: The devil is always in the detail, isn't he?  Anyway, I'm glad if I could help ;)